# R: Change color igraph based on condition if element in list of elements

Tags: r, if-statement, igraph

I have an iGraph object. I want to change the color of certain subnodes to lightblue, while all others are orange.

The following code is returning false for all nodes, thus all nodes are returned as orange. Why is this?

```
V(sub_net)
> 20/20 vertices, named, from 348f7f4:
> [1] 115 325 423 446 482 485 487 491 492 511 512 517 518 519 521 523 541 561 621 712

typeof(V(sub_net)[1])
> [1] "integer"

V(sub_net)$color <- ifelse(V(sub_net) %in% c(511,   541, 518, 519),"lightblue", "orange")

V(sub_net)$color
> [1] "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange"
>[11] "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange" "orange"
```

My code shows that there are 20 nodes, of type integer, and tries to reassign 511, 541, 518, and 519 to lightblue (else orange). But when I plot the graph, all nodes are orange.

I believe me ifelse statement is to blame but I don't understand the issue.

Adding some more context as to how I derived my data:

```
infile<-"MergerNet_Jan21_2016_forR.csv"
## Load package
library(igraph)
el = read.csv(infile, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
g_acq = graph.data.frame(el, directed = TRUE, vertices= NULL)

### List of all the years represented in the set
el[,"year"]
df <- data.frame(el)
class(df$weight)
# ---
#[1] "integer"
# ---

class(df$source)
# ---
# [1] "factor"
# ---

class(el)
# ---
# [1] "data.frame"
# ---

# Edges
ecount(g_acq)
## Vertices
vcount(g_acq)

#Is it a simple graph? No!
## Check whether Self_loops exist, as do multiple edges
is.simple(g_acq)
# ---
#[1] FALSE
# ---
E(g_acq)$weight 
g_acq_simpl<-simplify(g_acq)
### The above should default to the option below, to sum the existing edge weights ### when combining them
##g_acq_simpl<-simplify(g_acq,edge.attr.comb="sum" )

E(g_acq_simpl)$weight 
# Will use the inverse of log weight for shortest path calculations
inv_weight<-1/log(E(g_acq_simpl)$weight  + 1)
num_weight<-E(g_acq_simpl)$weight 
length(inv_weight)

# Remove disconnected components to create a strongly connected component. We will use this component to calculate closeness and shortest path distances.
g_acq_scc <-g_acq_simpl - vertices('814', '925', '928')
inv_weight_scc<-1/log(E(g_acq_scc)$weight  + 1)

plot(g_acq_scc)
sub_net<-induced.subgraph(g_acq_simpl, v=c('511', '541',
                                           '518', '519', '517', '325', '423', '446', '512', '523',
                                           '561', '621', '115', '482', '485', '487', '491', '492',
                                           '521', '712' ))
```

Note, I have since altered my code to try both integer and string arguments, but the following returned false, to my confusion:

```
V(sub_net) %in% c(511, 541, 518, 518)
>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE [20] FALSE

is.element(el = V(sub_net),set=c(511, 541, 518, 518))
>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE [20] FALSE

V(sub_net) %in% c('511', '541', '518', '518')
>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE [20] FALSE

is.element(el = V(sub_net),set=c('511', '541', '518', '518'))
>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE [20] FALSE
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't give error though. Would you mind sharing the data and the graph to replicate your syntax?

Comment: I've done that now, visible in the second code block

Comment: Thanks, but without at least a snippet of the data `"MergerNet_Jan21_2016_forR.csv"` I can't reproduce your graph. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to see how to share example data to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting your `ifelse` statement inside the `plot`, in the `vertex.color` argument like this:

```
plot(sub_net, vertex.color= ifelse(V(sub_net) %in% c(511, 541, 518, 519),"lightblue", "orange"))
```

edit:
from [here](https://coderedirect.com/questions/587422/how-to-specify-the-labels-of-vertices-in-r)

`V(sub_net)` should be changed to `V(sub_net)$name` to return the correct output

Comment: I tried this as well; it appears that the conditional statement, triggered no errors; it simply returned false for all elements. Real brain puzzler.